# Rcpp regex in interactive session, where is boost/regex.hpp

Tags: r, regex, rcpp

Can you please help me with my first experience of Rcpp with regex?
I tried to replicate the [gallery example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/), but unfortunately I get an error. Here is how I am trying it. 
First, I created test.cpp file and pasted the content from the example above.
Second, I created test.R file with the the following:

```
library(Rcpp)
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-lboost_regex")
sourceCpp('test.cpp')
```

Finally, when I run the test.R program it gives ERROR:

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/Users/manukyae/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/manukyae/Documents/R/R-3.4.3/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/manukyae/DOCUME~1/RWORK~1/UHOSTJ~1"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c test.cpp -o test.o
test.cpp:6:27: fatal error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/Users/manukyae/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/manukyae/DOCUME~1/R/R-34~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_6.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="test.o"' had status 2 
Error in sourceCpp("test.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Comment: Show your code. What is inside `test.cpp`?

Comment: Do you understand what the Gallery post is saying (ever so briefly) in "We need to set linker options. ".  It implies you _must gave the library and headers built and installed and findable by the compiler_.  Ie your issue here.

Comment: Try adding `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` at the top of your cpp file.

Comment: Won't help with the linking.

Comment: Hi @coatless, the code is the linked gallery example.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, I really do not undersand what the 'set linker options' means. I am just trying to reproduce the example in an interactive session, within R Studio.

Comment: Hi @F.Privé, I tried adding `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` in .cpp file and now I get the following error:
C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_regex
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Edgar: you can't. Boost regex needs an external library you would need to install.  I'll make the Gallery post more explicit about that.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thank you so much for committing to this. I am sure that the growing community of Rcpp users is going to appreciate that!